# "make: go: command not found" - although go binary is in $PATH

Tags: go, makefile, raspberry-pi, runc

I want to build runC on a Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster), Linux 4.19.97-v7+.

I downloaded the go1.15.6 ARMv6 version, extracted it to `/usr/local` and updated `$PATH` & `$GOPATH`.

`go version` returns

```
go version go1.15.6 linux/arm
```

and `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Following the [instructions](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc) for building runC, running `sudo make install` returns

```
make: go: command not found
install -D -m0755 runc /usr/local/sbin/runc
```

Why doesn't it find the go binary?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I'm aware, `sudo` runs the program as the root user, not your current user. As such, it may be the case where the `$PATH` obtained by the Makefile is not the same as it is on your current user.

To fix this, you could run `sudo -E make install`, where `-E` ensures that your environment is preserved.

Comment: Hey John, this approach worked for me, though I had to modify the command to 
`sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" make install` for it to work. Thx for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

make has its own PATH. Consult make‘s documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means: make uses the same path as the shell that started it.  Of course you can modify it from within your makefile.